# Read file from classpath in Android Studio (LibGDX)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I decided to move from Eclipse to Android Studio. I read the list of levels from levelsList.cfg. It is in my core module.

```
FileHandle cfgFile = Gdx.files.classpath("levelsList.cfg");
reader = cfgFile.reader(256);
```

It's working in Eclipse just fine. In Android Studio I've got

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: levelsList.cfg (Classpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android it is more convenient to use `Gdx.files.internal();` function and put your files to `$ANDROID_PROJECT/assets/data` folder. 
Or read GDX documentation and try to work out the method that allows put your file with your classes

Here is part from GDX documentation: 
"On Android the situation is a little bit more complex. Files can be stored inside the application's APK either as resources or as assets. These files are read-only. Libgdx only uses the assets mechanism ... Assets are stored in your Android project's assets directory and will be packaged with your APK automatically when you deploy your application. No other application on the Android system can access these files." $ANDROID_PROJECT/assets/data

Comment: The problem is it's not safe to keep that info in assets. Everyone with rooted android can change data there.